# How to crawl through Google drive files using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, ambar

I want to crawl and index Google drive files using elastic search from my Google account, I also want to know can we crawl and index public  Google drive files, I have tried this github link,

https://github.com/RD17/ambar/blob/master/README.md

But this doesn't have Google drive integration instead it has drop box integration.

Comment: @dadoonet could fscrawler help here?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used Ambar to mount Google Drive and search through files
 ([ElasticSearch is a core Ambar component for performing search](https://blog.ambar.cloud/ambar-under-the-hood/))

Ambar do not have Google Drive integration as of now. What you can do is mount Google Drive as a Samba share or a network drive in your Ambar server.

Once it is successfully mounted or available through a network drive, you can modify your `docker-compose` file and add a new `crawler` for that mount point/network drive as follows,

```
crawler0:
    depends_on: 
      serviceapi: 
        condition: service_healthy 
    image: ambar/ambar-local-crawler
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    environment:
      - apiUrl=http://serviceapi:8081
      - name=crawler_google
    volumes:
      - /tmp:/usr/data
```

`/tmp` is the path to `smb` share, in my case its a google drive.

Stop and Start your docker containers before testing.

hope it helps